# What's the best place to discuss something privately?

Tags: privacy, collaboration, forums

I've been considering putting together a business proposal, and I would like to find a place to discuss this online with other collaborators privately. I also want to make sure that the data doesn't get leaked to the public somehow. I would prefer not to have to pay much or anything, but I'm willing to pay a small amount of money if it's absolutely required. What services do you recommend?

EDIT: After having this up here for a while, I've realized I should probably add in a bit more things to help clarify what I want.

1. I don't care if the host can read it, so long as they agree not to disclose it to outside sources, or to profit off of it at all. But I'm not so paranoid that the data has to be encrypted on their server.
2. I'm assuming that anyone who has access to the site has access, and I don't need to protect the information that is on this site.
3. I want it to be a form that promotes collaboration, a form, SE style, wiki style, anything that makes it easy to collect ideas would be ideal.

Hope these tidbits help.

Comment: In the toilets is best. Anything online will always have a digital leak.

Comment: I think this is a fair question.

Comment: "trying to make digital files uncopyable is like trying to make water not wet." --Bruce Schneier. Are you trying to keep people involved from leaking information, or just 3rd parties?

Comment: Just third parties, I know that anyone who has access will inevitably be able to copy all information. I do want to restrict who can see it, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own Private Wiki at [Wikispaces](http://www.wikispaces.com).

You would need to upgrade to the [Plus Package for Individuals and Groups](http://www.wikispaces.com/content/pricing) in order have a private wiki.  This costs $5 a month or $50 a year and provides the following features:

- Unlimited Users
- Unlimited Pages and Messages
- 2GB Storage
- Max 20MB Per File
- WYSIWYG Editing
- Ad Free
- Private Wiki
- SSL Security
- Custom Themes

Answer (score 1):

Google docs can be shared with other people, are reasonably private (so long as they don't share with others) and can support multiple updates I think.

Google Wave would have been the ideal place to do this but they aren't continuing support for it (although it looks likely that the main features will be built into google docs at some point soon).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [zoho.com](http://zoho.com). They provide multiple tools for collaboration projects. Much more possibilities than on google apps.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook. Frankly, there is no completely safe place to have private discussion. Even toilet is not safe enough. It is better use your own codding

Comment: I'm sorry, but Facebook is the #1 site I was trying to avoid... They are famous for privacy leaks, and Terms of Service which allow them to use the information they gather. Not the solution I want...

Comment: What terms allows them to use your private messages? Could you show an example?

Comment: It's not so much that they do now, it's that in the past they've had some pretty scary examples... Still, I did read their policy, and it looks to be better than it was in the past.

Answer (score -2):

I think that [proofhub](http://www.proofhub.com) is the best place to discuss something privately. This software provides private discussions which are really awesome.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this site? Please disclose any affiliation, and try to describe *why* the software meets the OP's needs.